# Alternatives to makepkg command in Solaris 11 that does not use SVR4

Tags: shell, solaris, packaging, archlinux

Currently I am packaging my libraries and binaries using makepkg, since this uses SVR4 set of commands I wanted to get rid off this. I am looking for such packaging that support in Solaris 11 which is as simple as makepkg. I know IPS is available, but no idea how to use that.

Currently I have a script which takes all these binaries and libraries, creates version, and does package using makepkg.

Are any alternatives to makepkg available that does not use SVR4?

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/admin-o11-097-create-pkg-ips.html

Comment: you could try to use offload-build in devtools and build your packages on a remote arch linux machine.. but I am not sure if this is what you want.